# Can I switch to another branch, commit to it, and switch back, in a commit-msg hook?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I want to insert the first few chars of the commit hash and the commit message automatically into a file in the `gh-pages` branch any time that I commit to `master`.

Currently using this `post-commit` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Ensures we are in master branch
[ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` != "master" ] && exit 1
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
# update the js file with commit identification information from git
# I can't seem to get this to work without generating a *_bak file. Whatever.
# I have a section in my source that has delimiters #% %# that I use to stuff the
# git commit into, so I can view the version of source I am testing on my device
# very easily (you can't imagine how much more definite and efficient this is compared
# to what we do at my work)
sed -i _bak "s/#%.*%#/#% `git log master -1 --format="%h %s"` %#/" source.js
git commit -a -m"this commit made by a script"
git checkout master
```

I doubt that converting this into a `commit-msg` hook would allow me to reduce the amount of extra commits generated (two, one to merge master into gh-pages, and one to write in the commit-msg I used for the master commit into the file) whenever I perform a commit on `master`, but it would at least allow me to easily skip it by doing a `commit -n` for `--no-verify`, whereas with a `post-commit` hook I'd have to unset the exec flag on the hook file to temporarily disable it.

Does this work? I guess I should just try it. What will Git do, though? So long as my bash script issues a return-value of 0 it will proceed to perform the commit?

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, a solution for your hook would be to do those same command in a different local repo (already checked out to `gh-pages`), with `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options to your git command (in order to reference that other repo).

And then fetch that branch back in your repo (still in the same hook).

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So you could simply update a subfolder content in the same branch now.

Answer (score 0):

Commit is not the big problem. You can't really use `git commit` itself, but you can create a commit using the plumbing commands (that allows you to add commit to another branch using separate index file without actually touching the work tree). The bigger problem is the **merge**, because it can fail and leave the tree in state that requires manual intervention.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "you can't really use git commit itself"?

You do bring up a good point and I did have to resolve a conflict today in this merge due to me touching the code that is affected by my script. I only need it to work in the event that the change in `master` does not produce a merge conflict.